# Create a website for adding supplementary material of a journal paper

Tags: peer-review, ieee, website, supporting-information

I just got the reviews for the paper I submitted to IEEE TCSVT and one of the reviewers asked me to provide them with some supplementary results. I am planning the create a website for them so they can go and download the results. Any suggestions on how I can create such a website for my paper?

Comment: why not just email them?

Comment: The files are High Dynamic Range (HDR) video files which are very large in size.

Comment: In this case, you can upload it to Youtube as a private video (or setting a password). Then give them the link, such that only they can open it. See https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: What about figshare vor zenodo? Many supplementary materials can be found there.

Comment: Is the material supposed to be private between you and the reviewers (as @Nathan Explosion 's comment suggests)?

Comment: @carlosvalderrama When I (with my reviewer hat on) write something like "could the authors provide additional data" I certainly mean "provide to the general audience of your paper, should it be accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option for you might be uploading your files (videos) to

1. Google Drive, Dropbox. Share your files as links and send to the reviewers. No one else can see these files, and they are very secured.

For sharing your files using Google Drive, check https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

**I strongly suggest not to create a website for file downloading, if your are not experienced with website development.** It is much complicated for beginners. You need to find (vps, dedicated) servers, then install OS, dependencies, web servers (nginx, apaches) etc., and enable ftp or something else.

So, just upload to a google drive, and share to them.

Comment: If anyone is reading this (and I *know* this answer isn't even recommending setting up your own server), don't do FTP no matter how tech-confident you are. FTP is too far gone a technology: not even web browsers are bothering to support them any more. For downloads people use the web server. For personal uploads you can use the ssh-based sftp. (Just came back from unsuccessfully hunting down a 1-year-old FTP link and it hurts.)

Answer (score 4):

Please use existing repositories when showing your supplementary data. Department websites die more often than we'd like.

Some options include:

- [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/)
- [Dryad](https://datadryad.org/)
- [Figshare](http://figshare.com/)

See also https://www.nature.com/sdata/policies/repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Github Pages is the dead simple, amazing, and (kind of) permanent way.